# Spark Datagrid with Splitted columns

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I'm trying to figure out how can i get that a simple Datagrid has splitted columns.

I need the following layout:

```
   +-------------------+
   |    Destination    |
   +--------+----------+
   | Dir 1  |  Dir 2   |
   +-------------------+
```

Any idea about how could I do it?

Comment: Create a custom renderer that displays Dir 1 + Dir 2 - style it so it looks to the user that it is 2 separate cells

Comment: Hi Lee, maybe a good idea but not figure out how to implement it as an itemRenderer. Any example, please?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-7ff3.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use a header renderer for the same. Customized renderers can be created.